# Data Dog Does not push/send JMX metrics when tomcat path is diffrent

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, datadog

I have installed my tomcat on different locations and I have enabled JMX Metric.
Data Dog Agent collects the metrics but it does not push metrics to data dog.

***Data Dog Agent Status***

```
========
JMXFetch
========

  Information
  ==================
    runtime_version : 11.0.6
    version : 0.44.6
  Initialized checks
  ==================
    jmx
      instance_name : test server
      message : <no value>
      metric_count : 165
      service_check_count : 0
      status : OK
  Failed checks
  =============
    no checks
```

***Tomcat is configured to enable JMX with a JMX password. But tomcat is installed in a different path***

****I think this could be due to the tomcat path being different****
tomcat path is `/opt/tomcat`

***DATA DOG AGENT JMX LOGS AS FOLLOWS***

```
2022-01-21 11:42:46 IST | JMX | INFO | ConnectionFactory | Connecting using JMX Remote
2022-01-21 11:42:46 IST | JMX | INFO | Connection | Connecting to: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
2022-01-21 11:42:46 IST | JMX | INFO | Instance | Trying to collect bean list for the first time for JMX Server at test server
2022-01-21 11:42:46 IST | JMX | INFO | Instance | Connected to JMX Server at test server
2022-01-21 11:42:47 IST | JMX | INFO | Instance | Found 159 matching attributes
2022-01-21 11:42:47 IST | JMX | INFO | Instance | Done initializing JMX Server at test server
2022-01-21 11:42:47 IST | JMX | INFO | App | Completed instance initialization...
2022-01-21 11:42:47 IST | JMX | INFO | App | Successfully initialized instance: test server
2022-01-21 11:42:47 IST | JMX | INFO | Reporter | Instance test-server is sending 165 metrics to the metrics reporter during collection #1
2022-01-21 11:43:01 IST | JMX | INFO | Reporter | Instance test-server is sending 165 metrics to the metrics reporter during collection #2
2022-01-21 11:43:16 IST | JMX | INFO | Reporter | Instance test-server is sending 165 metrics to the metrics reporter during collection #3
2022-01-21 11:43:31 IST | JMX | INFO | Reporter | Instance test-server is sending 165 metrics to the metrics reporter during collection #4
2022-01-21 11:43:46 IST | JMX | INFO | Reporter | Instance test-server is sending 165 metrics to the metrics reporter during collection #5
2022-01-21 11:43:46 IST | JMX | INFO | Reporter | Next collections will be logged only every 10 collections.
```

```
conf:
    - include:
        type: ThreadPool
        attribute:
          maxThreads:
            alias: tomcat.threads.max
            metric_type: gauge
          currentThreadCount:
            alias: tomcat.threads.count
            metric_type: gauge
          currentThreadsBusy:
            alias: tomcat.threads.busy
            metric_type: gauge
    - include:
        type: GlobalRequestProcessor
        attribute:
          bytesSent:
            alias: tomcat.bytes_sent
            metric_type: counter
          bytesReceived:
            alias: tomcat.bytes_rcvd
            metric_type: counter
          errorCount:
            alias: tomcat.error_count
            metric_type: counter
          requestCount:
            alias: tomcat.request_count
            metric_type: counter
          maxTime:
            alias: tomcat.max_time
            metric_type: gauge
          processingTime:
            alias: tomcat.processing_time
            metric_type: counter
    - include:
        j2eeType: Servlet
        attribute:
          processingTime:
            alias: tomcat.servlet.processing_time
            metric_type: counter
          errorCount:
            alias: tomcat.servlet.error_count
            metric_type: counter
          requestCount:
            alias: tomcat.servlet.request_count
            metric_type: counter
    - include:
        type: Cache
        attribute:
          accessCount:
            alias: tomcat.cache.access_count
            metric_type: counter
          hitsCounts:
            alias: tomcat.cache.hits_count
            metric_type: counter
    - include:
        type: JspMonitor
        attribute:
          jspCount:
            alias: tomcat.jsp.count
            metric_type: counter
          jspReloadCount:
            alias: tomcat.jsp.reload_count
            metric_type: counter
```

Comment: Can you share the JMX config (without sensitive data, of course)? Do you have any [filters](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/java/?tab=host#description-of-the-filters)?

Comment: I shared on the question post @bwest

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your `include` filters are not matching any attributes, which is why metrics are not being sent. You can debug this and find the appropriate attributes by using the [troubleshooting commands](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/faq/troubleshooting-jmx-integrations/?tab=agentv6v7#agent-troubleshooting).

In order, I suggest:

1. `sudo -u dd-agent datadog-agent jmx list collected` to see what is collected
2. `sudo -u dd-agent datadog-agent jmx list matching` to find what is matching your configuration
3. if your attributes match, `sudo -u dd-agent datadog-agent jmx list limited` to see if thresholds are limiting what is collected
4. if they don't, `sudo -u dd-agent datadog-agent jmx list not-matching` to see what is not matching.

Then adjust your configuration and try again.